# There is an false error output on @Override. How do I fix it?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

So yeah, I have an issue where I can't test my Minecraft mod, and it does not explain what's the cause. I've done it correctly, yet I can't get over this error. Its a toilet mod. IDE I use is IntelliJ. It's also on fabric, if you are a forge modder. There's no further explanation.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLqii.png)

[This is the output I get. The output just shows me the error, and I've tried the suggestions, but it seems to worsen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXtex.png)

```java
@Override
    public void onInitialize() {

        Registry.register(Registry.BLOCK, new Identifier("toilet", "ceramic_toilet"), CERAMIC_TOILET);
        Registry.register(new Identifier("toilet", "ceramic_toilet"), new BlockItem(CERAMIC_TOILET, new Item.Settings().group((ItemGroup.MISC)));

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this false error"? Please [edit] the question to include the exact error message you're seeing.

Comment: @IMSoP i've setted up correctly, but i still don't know why there is an error at ```@Override```

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what error you're seeing. We can't see your screen, you have to tell us.

Comment: Take out the semicolon that you put after `@Override`, and next time show us the same code that you're actually trying to compile and run.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you provide, as Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica suggests: it's a syntax error.
The `@Override` annotation should not have a semicolon after it.

Also your second register method is missing a closing bracket, add another one like so:

```
Registry.register(new Identifier("toilet", "ceramic_toilet"), new BlockItem(CERAMIC_TOILET, new Item.Settings().group((ItemGroup.MISC))));
```